# send mail SQL Server with Dynamic smtp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sendmail, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

That's basically it.

i've configured the profile, mail, smtp server, username and password.
I'm using **sp_send_dbmail** but occasionally I'm going to change the smtp, username, password and port, I have that in a table and I just need to the pass parameters to the **"sp_send_dbmail"** with those fields, or something that works like that.

SQL Send mail with dynamically email credentials.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs it, First I delete the profile settings (Or account in this case) and then I'll create it again, using this...

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_delete_account_sp
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_delete_profile_sp

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
```

That's how i manage to "Update" Accounts credentials before sending the Mails

Answer (score 2):

You will have to store all the profile names that you have configured in your table.

```
declare @profilename varchar(50);

set @profilename = (select profilename from your_table where smpt_server = 'smtp_server_value');

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'Test@xyz.com'
, @subject = 'Subject'
, @body = 'email_test'
, @profile_name = @profilename
, @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Comment: With that I could choose between profiles, but the problem is the credentials, email Username, password and smtpserver

Comment: As long as you have setup the profile in DBMail with the correct credentials, all you need is the profile name.

Comment: The credentials will change every week, and the new credential will be in a table